# Melhor prática de persistência de dados

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Quando se trata de persistir os dados com o `Core Data`. Qual é a melhor maneira de persistir os dados?

Por exemplo:

> Possuo um objeto `Pessoa` (subclasse de `NSObject`). E no momento da
>   persistencia eu "converto" o `PessoaMO` (subclasse de
>   `NSManagedObject`).

O que eu queria saber, é basicamente o seguinte:

A maneira correta de fazer isso, é como o exemplo citado acima ou diretamente com o `NSManagedObject` sem ter a classe `Pessoa` (subclasse de `NSObject`)?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/101

Comment: Você precisa somente da classe que deriva de NSManagedObject. O que você mexer nela irá automaticamente ser salvo. A não ser que precise mesmo de uma cópia temporária do objeto para trabalhar com ele por um tempo sem salvar, o que não é algo comum.

Answer (score 1):

Essa sua solução parece desrespeitar o DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) pois além de existir uma duplicação no código as classes PessoaMO e Pessoa vão ser dependentes. (Qualquer mudança em uma quebra a outra).

Uma solução seria user diversos com NSManagedObjectContext's para fazer um melhor controle do que será persistido e o que será descartado. (Creio que seja isso que você esteja fazendo).